# Play Framework, Hibernate and too slow insertation

Tags: performance, hibernate, playframework

I have two models: User and Base.

User model:
http://pastebin.com/WdLzBkHJ

Base model:
http://pastebin.com/tQrEUaSu

At first I want to put your mind on this notation in Base model:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.Entity(dynamicInsert=true,dynamicUpdate=true)
```

It doesn't work (in SQL Debug shown that Hibernate generated queries with using unnecessary columns which in MySQL are configured as nullable). Tell me please why? What am I doing wrong?

And the main problem is there (method in which user uploads base and string in this base inserts in the MySQL table after parsing):
http://pastebin.com/yG3Mapze

Insertation is VERY SLOW. I have file with 70000 string per line and I can't wait until Hibernate insert this string into DB. Maximum I was waiting for 30 minutes and that wasn't the end.
If I'll use raw queries like that:

```
DB.execute("INSERT INTO bases (user_id,email,password) VALUES (1,'" + email.replaceAll("'", "\'") + "','" + password.replaceAll("'", "\'") + "')");
```

instead of

```
b.save();
```

After that insertation of 70000 strings to DB completes after ~10-20 seconds.
So I can't understand where is the problem and how to fix it?

Also you can see this code above method declaration:

```
@NoTransaction
```

If I uncomment it then I'll recieve this exception:

@689mbad1k
Internal Server Error (500) for request POST /checker/uploadnewbase

JPA error
A JPA error occurred (The JPA context is not initialized. JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.):

play.exceptions.JPAException: The JPA context is not initialized. JPA Entity Manager automatically start when one or more classes annotated with the @javax.persistence.Entity annotation are found in the application.
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.get(JPA.java:22)
    at play.db.jpa.JPA.em(JPA.java:51)
    at play.db.jpa.JPQL.em(JPQL.java:16)
    at play.db.jpa.JPQL.find(JPQL.java:44)
    at models.User.find(User.java)
    at controllers.Security.getUser(Security.java:30)
    at controllers.GlobalController.userStat(GlobalController.java:21)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:476)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:471)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.handleBefores(ActionInvoker.java:320)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:140)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)

But in Play manual we can see that:
"If you want to prevent Play from starting any transaction at all, you can annotate the method with @play.db.jpa.NoTransaction.

To prevent transactions for all methods, you can annotate the Controller-class with @play.db.jpa.NoTransaction."

So I have three problems which I described:

1. About exception in NoTransaction.
2. About using dynamicInsert = true.
3. About improving perfomance for Hibernate like if I'll use raw queries.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the hibernate session, which must be cleared. Otherwise you get problems with memory and performance. You can found some information in http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/batch.html. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the HibernateSession. Perhaps you can get the EntityManager and work with it. But my experiences with Hibernate and Batch are really frustrating, so I would recommend to use your raw-solution.

Comment: Yes thanks I already read about batch on jboss.org and results are frustrated me. Insertations are too slow. So I am using now raw-solution for this loop. But I can't understand _what_ Hibernate do except setting model properties and why is insertation so slow.

Comment: By the way don't you know solution for dynamicInsert and exception after NoTransaction?

Comment: @purple: I'm not a hibernate-expert, but as far as I know, there are many meta-information which must be handled in the background, which are increased exponential. About your question: I have no idea.

Comment: You can get the Play hibernate session with `Session session = (Session) JPA.em().getDelegate();` and then use `session.flush`` and `session.clear()` as described in the documentation in the answer. You may also make a new session exclusively for you're import.